# Valor de variável mudando de acordo com um select

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou com o seguinte problema, pessoal:

Tenho uma variável `$soma_produtos = 0` (Pega valores do banco através de um foreach)

Pegando os dados do foreach ficaria mais ou menos assim: `$soma_produtos += $produto->getPreco();`

Outra `$desconto = $soma_produtos * 0.05`

E por fim o `$total = $soma_produtos - $desconto`

O problema é o seguinte, quero que o valor de desconto seja mudado (atualizado sem dar refresh) de acordo com um select que eu tenho (isso sem dar submit)
o select é assim

```
<select class="modo-pagamento" id="modo_pagamento">
    <option value="1">Depósito bancário (5% de desconto)</option>
    <option value="2">Pag Seguro</option>
</select>
```

Ou seja, se o select me retornar 1, uso o desconto da forma que eu passei lá em cima, se não, não passo desconto nenhum.

Comment: Poste como está sua lógica no php.

Comment: Mas é basicamente isso @DiegoFelipe. Tenho a variável total que vai receber a soma dos produtos listados($soma_produtos) e também o desconto... O desconto pode variar, dependendo da opção do select

Comment: O problema é que você está citando variaveis php, mas colocou as tags de javascript. Se a logica estiver no php, vc precisa adicionar aqui. Ou é somente em javascript?

Comment: Sem refresh isso terá que ser feito do lado do cliente, provavelmente com JS. PHP roda no servidor. Uma dica: procure fazer as próximas perguntas já com todos os detalhes, pois [a edição que você fez](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/98252/revisions) muda completamente o problema, e prejudica as respostas dadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já eu disse, recomenda-se que se separe as partes, deixa o *php* agir no servidor, e depois faz o restante à partir do que se receber.

```
<form id="compra" method="POST">
<select name="produtos" class="produtos" id="produtos">
    <option value="1">Item 1 (10$)</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2 (50$)</option>
</select>
x <input type="number" min="1" value="1" name="quantidade" id="quantidade">
<select name="pagamento" class="modo-pagamento" id="modo_pagamento">
    <option value="1">Deposito bancario (5% desconto)</option>
    <option value="2">Pag Seguro</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="visualiza">
<span class="desconto"></span>
<span class="valor-total"></span>
</div>
```

Delinear as duas tags `span`:

```
<style type="text/css">
#visualiza > span { display: block; }
</style>
```

Requisição ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#compra').on('change', function(){
        var modo = $('#modo_pagamento').val();
        var produto = $('#produtos').val();
        var quantidade = $('#quantidade').val();
        var desconto, total;
        //var dados = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {produto: produto, quantidade: quantidade, desconto: modo},
            success: function(data){
             total = 'Total: ' + data.total +'$';
             desconto = 'Descontos: (' + data.perc_desconto + '%) pelo '+ data.resp_desconto;
             $('.valor-total').html(total); 
             $('.desconto').html(desconto);
             },
            error: function(i){ alert('erro'); }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Por último, o script *php* a operar no lado do servidor, e retorna os valores de acordo com os dados que lhe forem passados, para serem posteriormente organizadas sem necessitar do *php*.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8;");

# produtos existentes
$produtos = array(
    1=> array('nome'=>'item1', 'preco'=>10),
    2=> array('nome'=>'item2', 'preco'=>50) 
    );
# descontos existentes  
$descontos = array(
    1=> array('nome'=>'Deposito bancario', 'perc'=>5),
    2=> array('nome'=>'Pag Seguro', 'perc'=>0)
    );  

# requisiçoes   
$produto = isset($_POST['produto']) ? $_POST['produto'] : false;
$quantidade = isset($_POST['quantidade']) ? $_POST['quantidade'] : false;
$c_desconto = isset($_POST['desconto']) ? $_POST['desconto'] : false;

# reset dos valores
$nome = $r_desconto = "";
$total = $preco = $p_desconto = 0;

if($produto):
    $nome = $produtos[$produto]['nome'];
    $preco = $produtos[$produto]['preco'];
    $total = $preco * $quantidade;
    if($c_desconto):
        $p_desconto = $descontos[$c_desconto]['perc'];
        $r_desconto = $descontos[$c_desconto]['nome'];
        $total = $total - ($total * $p_desconto/100);
    endif;  
endif;

# organizar a saida
$retorno = array(
    'total'=>$total,
    'produto'=>$nome,
    'preco'=>$preco,
    'quantidade'=>$quantidade,
    'perc_desconto'=>$p_desconto,
    'resp_desconto'=>$r_desconto
    );
/*  
print $nome . " (".$preco."$) " . " x " . $quantidade;
print "<br/>";
print "total: " . $total;
print "<br/>";
print "descontos: " . $p_desconto . "% pelo " . $r_desconto;
*/

# saida json:
print json_encode($retorno);
```

Comment: Perfeito! Valeu!

Comment: Não tens de quê, é uma questão de saber, como queres que os valores retornados serão apresentados.

Answer (score 3):

Será disto que estás à procura?

```
<?php
    tem_desconto = 0;
    tem_desconto = $_POST["modo_pagamento"];
    $soma_produtos = 0
    if (tem_desconto == 1)
        $desconto = $soma_produtos * 0.05
    $total = $soma_produtos - $desconto
?>
```

Comment: É basicamente isso. Porém quero que o valor o valor total mude para o usuário sem precisão de um "refresh" na página...

Comment: @Naldson Para que uma parte da página mude sem que o resto seja alterado terás de usar uma técnica chamada de AJAX. Aconselho-te a dar uma vista de olhos ao JQuery uma biblioteca javascript capaz de produzir essa técnica de forma bastante mais fácil.